# Laravel dd output coming with script only

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

The response of `dd('asd')` coming with script tag , not plain string. For other php variable also the output of `dd()` coming with script tag only (no html tag). So, it's preview also looks like same as response. I'm using wampserver 3.1.0 .Earlier it was working fine with php 7.1, but when I switched to 7.0 this problem happening. Xdebug extension is enabled -

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.23/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.0-
vc14-x86_64.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
```

The response looks like this -

```
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9660;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9654;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = s.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-(compact|expanded)\b/, newClass); if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (-1 == a[s].className.indexOf(newClass)) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; function collapse(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function expand(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function collapseAll(root) { var a = root.querySelector('a.sf-dump-toggle'); if (a) { collapse(a, true); expand(a); return true; } return false; } function reveal(node) { var previous, parents = []; while ((node = node.parentNode || {}) && (previous = node.previousSibling) && 'A' === previous.tagName) { parents.push(previous); } if (0 !== parents.length) { parents.forEach(function (parent) { expand(parent); }); return true; } return false; } function highlight(root, activeNode, nodes) { resetHighlightedNodes(root); Array.from(nodes||[]).forEach(function (node) { if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/.test(node.className)) { node.className = node.className + ' sf-dump-highlight'; } }); if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/.test(activeNode.className)) { activeNode.className = activeNode.className + ' sf-dump-highlight-active'; } } function resetHighlightedNodes(root) { Array.from(root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str, .sf-dump-key, .sf-dump-public, .sf-dump-protected, .sf-dump-private')).forEach(function (strNode) { strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/, ''); strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/, ''); }); } return function (root, x) { root = doc.getElementById(root); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\\$1')+')+', 'm'), options = {"maxDepth":1,"maxStringLength":160,"fileLinkFormat":false}, elt = root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, s, h, t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); for (i in x) { options[i] = x[i]; } function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } else if (e.target.nextElementSibling && 'A' == e.target.nextElementSibling.tagName) { f(e.target.nextElementSibling, e, true); } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey; } function xpathString(str) { var parts = str.match(/[^'"]+|['"]/g).map(function (part) { if ("'" == part) { return '"\'"'; } if ('"' == part) { return "'\"'"; } return "'" + part + "'"; }); return "concat(" + parts.join(",") + ", '')"; } addEventListener(root, 'mouseover', function (e) { if ('' != refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover', function (a, e, c) { if (c) { e.target.style.cursor = "pointer"; } else if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { try { refStyle.innerHTML = 'pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } catch (e) { } } }); a('click', function (a, e, c) { if (/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); if (!toggle(a, isCtrlKey(e))) { var r = doc.getElementById(a.getAttribute('href').substr(1)), s = r.previousSibling, f = r.parentNode, t = a.parentNode; t.replaceChild(r, a); f.replaceChild(a, s); t.insertBefore(s, r); f = f.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); t = t.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); if (f && t && f[0] !== t[0]) { r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('^'+f[0].replace(rxEsc, '\\$1'), 'mg'), t[0]); } if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(r.className)) { toggle(s, isCtrlKey(e)); } } if (c) { } else if (doc.getSelection) { try { doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); } catch (e) { doc.getSelection().empty(); } } else { doc.selection.empty(); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-str-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); e = a.parentNode.parentNode; e.className = e.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-str-(expand|collapse)\b/, a.parentNode.className); } }); elt = root.getElementsByTagName('SAMP'); len = elt.length; i = 0; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; if ('SAMP' == elt.tagName) { elt.className = 'sf-dump-expanded'; a = elt.previousSibling || {}; if ('A' != a.tagName) { a = doc.createElement('A'); a.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; elt.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elt); } else { a.innerHTML += ' '; } a.title = (a.title ? a.title+'\n[' : '[')+keyHint+'+click] Expand all children'; a.innerHTML += '<span>&#9660;</span>'; a.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; x = 1; if ('sf-dump' != elt.parentNode.className) { x += elt.parentNode.getAttribute('data-depth')/1; } elt.setAttribute('data-depth', x); if (x > options.maxDepth) { toggle(a); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-ref\b/.test(elt.className) && (a = elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a; if (/[\[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a != elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { s = a.nextSibling; elt.appendChild(a); s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s); if (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += ' <span>&#9654;</span>'; } else { elt.innerHTML = '<span>&#9654;</span>'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '&hellip;'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } } if (doc.evaluate && Array.from && root.children.length > 1) { root.setAttribute('tabindex', 0); SearchState = function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }; SearchState.prototype = { next: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx < (this.nodes.length - 1) ? this.idx + 1 : this.idx; return this.current(); }, previous: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx > 0 ? this.idx - 1 : this.idx; return this.current(); }, isEmpty: function () { return 0 === this.count(); }, current: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return null; } return this.nodes[this.idx]; }, reset: function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }, count: function () { return this.nodes.length; }, }; function showCurrent(state) { var currentNode = state.current(); if (currentNode) { reveal(currentNode); highlight(root, currentNode, state.nodes); } counter.textContent = (state.isEmpty() ? 0 : state.idx + 1) + ' of ' + state.count(); } var search = doc.createElement('div'); search.className = 'sf-dump-search-wrapper sf-dump-search-hidden'; search.innerHTML = ' <input type="text" class="sf-dump-search-input"> <span class="sf-dump-search-count">0 of 0<\/span> <button type="button" class="sf-dump-search-input-previous" tabindex="-1"> <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="M1683 1331l-166 165q-19 19-45 19t-45-19l-531-531-531 531q-19 19-45 19t-45-19l-166-165q-19-19-19-45.5t19-45.5l742-741q19-19 45-19t45 19l742 741q19 19 19 45.5t-19 45.5z"\/> <\/svg> <\/button> <button type="button" class="sf-dump-search-input-next" tabindex="-1"> <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="M1683 808l-742 741q-19 19-45 19t-45-19l-742-741q-19-19-19-45.5t19-45.5l166-165q19-19 45-19t45 19l531 531 531-531q19-19 45-19t45 19l166 165q19 19 19 45.5t-19 45.5z"\/> <\/svg> <\/button> '; root.insertBefore(search, root.firstChild); var state = new SearchState(); var searchInput = search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-input'); var counter = search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-count'); var searchInputTimer = 0; var previousSearchQuery = ''; addEventListener(searchInput, 'keyup', function (e) { var searchQuery = e.target.value; /* Don't perform anything if the pressed key didn't change the query */ if (searchQuery === previousSearchQuery) { return; } previousSearchQuery = searchQuery; clearTimeout(searchInputTimer); searchInputTimer = setTimeout(function () { state.reset(); collapseAll(root); resetHighlightedNodes(root); if ('' === searchQuery) { counter.textContent = '0 of 0'; return; } var xpathResult = doc.evaluate('//pre[@id="' + root.id + '"]//span[@class="sf-dump-str" or @class="sf-dump-key" or @class="sf-dump-public" or @class="sf-dump-protected" or @class="sf-dump-private"][contains(child::text(), ' + xpathString(searchQuery) + ')]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null); while (node = xpathResult.iterateNext()) state.nodes.push(node); showCurrent(state); }, 400); }); Array.from(search.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-search-input-next, .sf-dump-search-input-previous')).forEach(function (btn) { addEventListener(btn, 'click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); -1 !== e.target.className.indexOf('next') ? state.next() : state.previous(); searchInput.focus(); collapseAll(root); showCurrent(state); }) }); addEventListener(root, 'keydown', function (e) { var isSearchActive = !/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/.test(search.className); if ((114 === e.keyCode && !isSearchActive) || (isCtrlKey(e) && 70 === e.keyCode)) { /* F3 or CMD/CTRL + F */ e.preventDefault(); search.className = search.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/, ''); searchInput.focus(); } else if (isSearchActive) { if (27 === e.keyCode) { /* ESC key */ search.className += ' sf-dump-search-hidden'; e.preventDefault(); resetHighlightedNodes(root); searchInput.value = ''; } else if ( (isCtrlKey(e) && 71 === e.keyCode) /* CMD/CTRL + G */ || 13 === e.keyCode /* Enter */ || 114 === e.keyCode /* F3 */ ) { e.preventDefault(); e.shiftKey ? state.previous() : state.next(); collapseAll(root); showCurrent(state); } } }); } if (0 >= options.maxStringLength) { return; } try { elt = root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str'); len = elt.length; i = 0; t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; s = elt.innerText || elt.textContent; x = s.length - options.maxStringLength; if (0 < x) { h = elt.innerHTML; elt[elt.innerText ? 'innerText' : 'textContent'] = s.substring(0, options.maxStringLength); elt.className += ' sf-dump-str-collapse'; elt.innerHTML = '<span class=sf-dump-str-collapse>'+h+'<a class="sf-dump-ref sf-dump-str-toggle" title="Collapse"> &#9664;</a></span>'+ '<span class=sf-dump-str-expand>'+elt.innerHTML+'<a class="sf-dump-ref sf-dump-str-toggle" title="'+x+' remaining characters"> &#9654;</a></span>'; } } } catch (e) { } }; })(document); </script><style> pre.sf-dump { display: block; white-space: pre; padding: 5px; } pre.sf-dump:after { content: ""; visibility: hidden; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; } pre.sf-dump span { display: inline; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-compact { display: none; } pre.sf-dump abbr { text-decoration: none; border: none; cursor: help; } pre.sf-dump a { text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; border: 0; outline: none; color: inherit; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis { display: inline-block; overflow: visible; text-overflow: ellipsis; max-width: 5em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: top; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis+.sf-dump-ellipsis { max-width: none; } pre.sf-dump code { display:inline; padding:0; background:none; } .sf-dump-str-collapse .sf-dump-str-collapse { display: none; } .sf-dump-str-expand .sf-dump-str-expand { display: none; } .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight { background: rgba(111, 172, 204, 0.3); border: 1px solid #7DA0B1; border-radius: 3px; } .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight-active { background: rgba(253, 175, 0, 0.4); border: 1px solid #ffa500; border-radius: 3px; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-hidden { display: none; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper { float: right; font-size: 0; white-space: nowrap; max-width: 100%; text-align: right; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > * { vertical-align: top; box-sizing: border-box; height: 21px; font-weight: normal; border-radius: 0; background: #FFF; color: #757575; border: 1px solid #BBB; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > input.sf-dump-search-input { padding: 3px; height: 21px; font-size: 12px; border-right: none; width: 140px; border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; color: #000; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next, pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-previous { background: #F2F2F2; outline: none; border-left: none; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next { border-top-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next > svg, pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-previous > svg { pointer-events: none; width: 12px; height: 12px; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-count { display: inline-block; padding: 0 5px; margin: 0; border-left: none; line-height: 21px; font-size: 12px; }pre.sf-dump, pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-default{background-color:#fff; color:#222; line-height:1.2em; font-weight:normal; font:12px Monaco, Consolas, monospace; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap; position:relative; z-index:100000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-num{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-const{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-str{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-cchr{color:#222}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-note{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ref{color:#a0a0a0}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-public{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-protected{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-private{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-meta{color:#b729d9}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-key{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-index{color:#a71d5d}</style><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1777663630 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="3 characters">asd</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1777663630")</script>
```

Comment: Im also trying to figure out a way to be able to preview the ajax responses using dd like normal. Its quite tedious but what ive done is just copy the response into a html previewer and use that.

Comment: @Marungsha Brahma : did you get the solution for it ? I'm using php 7.1 version

Comment: @06011991 I'm currently using php 7.0.* .Didn't get the solution, just reinstalled.

Answer (score 5):

It's because of Chrome's latest update.
try calling

```
http_response_code(500);
```

before `dd('asd');`

as I am doing

```
http_response_code(500);
dd(VARIABLE_TO_DUMP);
```

OR

you can create a helper function with two statements given above. For eg:-

```
function my_dump($var) {
    http_response_code(500);
    dd($var);
}
```

Comment: I still have this problem after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```